# Issue With workflow rule

Tags: workflow, formula

```
OR(ISNEW(),ISCHANGED(Quantity),IF(Quantity > 14))
```

Giving me an error - "Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2"

Any one can help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need this `IF` function, as expression `Quantity > 14` already returns boolean result. Try:

```
OR(ISNEW(),ISCHANGED(Quantity), Quantity > 14)
```

But, I think, you want to group conditions as follows:

```
OR(ISNEW(), AND(ISCHANGED(Quantity), Quantity > 14))
```

as in your initial variant workflow will always fire if `Quantity > 14`